# Query JSON in CosmosDB to find strings that breach varchar limit

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

A few days ago I encountered a problem that was totally my bad, and now I need some help fixing some data.

I have some JSON documents stored in CosmosDB, and I have a function app to translate these JSON documents into an Azure SQL table. The error I encountered was that I put one of the columns as varchar 200, and the error was caused by strings in this JSON that exceed that character limit. A bit of an oversight, but I've put validation in place, and made it a much more robust process but I'm still left with a load of data that is unable to fulfil its purpose and I seem to be defeated by the querying limits of cosmosDB.

So my question is. How can I query cosmosDB to find the a document with strings that exceed 200 chars?

Here is an example of the JSON i'm trying to query stored in cosmosDB

```
{
    "title": "My Json Data",
    "questions": [
      {
        "type": "Options",
        "position": 0,
        "text": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "supportingQuestion": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "options": [
          {
            "position": 0,
            "text": "Strongly Agree"
          },
          {
            "position": 1,
            "text": "Agree"
          },
          {
            "position": 2,
            "text": "Neutral"
          },
          {
            "position": 3,
            "text": "Disagree"
          },
          {
            "position": 4,
            "text": "Strongly Disagree"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "type": "Options",
        "position": 1,
        "text": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "supportingQuestion": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "options": [
          {
            "position": 0,
            "text": "Strongly Agree"
          },
          {
            "position": 1,
            "text": "Agree"
          },
          {
            "position": 2,
            "text": "Neutral"
          },
          {
            "position": 3,
            "text": "Disagree"
          },
          {
            "position": 4,
            "text": "Strongly Disagree"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
}
```

I've tried searching around to see if there are any operators I can use for cosmos and I'm not having much luck at all.

With queries like this I can search for specific offenders, but not the general offenders I'm after.

SELECT * FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.questions, { text: "My question text"}, true)

Is there a way to search for c.questions text > 200?

I also tried downloading each document locally using a migration tool supplied by Microsoft so I could perhaps try to iterate through them.

```
        // Set some common query options.
        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };

        IQueryable<Forms> formQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Forms>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), queryOptions)
            .Where(f => f.FormType == "Evaluation");

        // Execute the query synchronously. 
        Console.WriteLine("Running LINQ query...");
        foreach (Forms FormType in formQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\tRead {FormType}");
        }

        // Now execute the same query using direct SQL.
        IQueryable<Forms> formQueryInSql = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Forms>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
            selectLabel.Text + @" " + QueryBox.Text,
            //"SELECT * FROM c",
            queryOptions);

        Console.WriteLine("Running direct SQL query...");
        foreach (Forms Item in formQueryInSql)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\tRead {Item.Id}");
        }
```

This code works wonderfully with smaller datasets, but not at all well with the large datasets I'm using. It hangs and crashes

Is there any simpler query I can use on the cosmosDB UI to get what I need? Or do I need to think about getting this through some clever code?

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of the SQL column?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT That is sort of what I'm aiming to do. But I don't want to raise it more than I have to for performance reasons. So I was hoping to find the longest string, and then set the number to be that number + 1. Then the column won't have to be any longer than it has to be.

Comment: Got it. Just to confirm, it looks like you are using the SQL API for Cosmos?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the SQL API so I will answer based on that assumption. You can create a query that iterates through the array of questions and pulls out the string lengths you are looking for.

You can run these queries through the portal or from the API, however the portal will sometimes choose to only work with a subset of data so the results might not be accurate. That means with a larger dataset you probably do want to run them from code, but the work of sorting through the values will be moved to CosmosDB instead of trying to load up everything on your local machine.

```
SELECT 
    c.position,
    c.text,
    LENGTH(c.text) AS textLength,
    c.supportingQuestion,
    LENGTH(c.supportingQuestion) AS supportingQuestionLength
FROM c IN items.questions
WHERE LENGTH(c.text) > 200 OR LENGTH(c.supportingQuestion) > 200
```

Your test Json creates this output (I reduced the filter to 20 so I would get results):

```
[
    {
        "position": 0,
        "text": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "textLength": 26,
        "supportingQuestion": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "supportingQuestionLength": 26
    },
    {
        "position": 1,
        "text": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "textLength": 26,
        "supportingQuestion": "POTENTIONALLY LARGE STRING",
        "supportingQuestionLength": 26
    }
]
```

If you are looking specifically the largest value in each field, you can add the `MAX` function to collapse the results down to that value.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(LENGTH(c.text)) AS textLength,
    MAX(LENGTH(c.supportingQuestion)) AS supportingQuestionLength
FROM c IN items.questions
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "textLength": 26,
        "supportingQuestionLength": 26
    }
]
```